# Get error the second time to write to sd card

Tags: sd-card, spi

I try to communicate by avr with micro SD.  Card is initializing properly in SPI mode. 
I can write 512 bytes of data for the first time in SD card. Data write operation is performed correctly. But for the second time will get an error and Data is not written in the SD card.
How to fix this error?
The code that I wrote.

```
unsigned int SD_write(long int Address,unsigned int data[],unsigned int k){
unsigned int j,er=0;
 CS_ENABLE();
 spi(0x58);
 spi(Address>>24);
 spi(Address>>16);
 spi(Address>>8);
 spi(Address);
 spi(0xff);
for(j=0; j<2000 && spi(0xFF)!=0x00; j++){} //whit for OK=0x00 reply
if(j>=2000) er=1;  //get error 1
 spi(0xFF);
 spi(0xFF);
 spi(0xFE);
for (j=0;j<k;j++)
 {
 spi(data[j]);
 }
for(j=k;j<512;j++)
 {
 spi(0x00);
 }

 spi(0x00);
 spi(0x00);
 spi(0x00);
for (j=0;j<2000&&spi(0xFF)!=0x00;j++){} //whit for 0x00 OK reply
if(j>=2000) er=2;  //get error 2
 CS_DISABLE();
return er;
```